# How to delete 0.1 percent of last observations

Tags: stata

I have variable `name` and `price`. I want to delete 0.1 percent of last observations of `price` for each `name`.

last observations are highest on `price`. There are no missing values.
If there aren't at least 1000 observations for each distinct `name`, just final observation deletes.

How can I do that using Stata?

Comment: What are the last observations? Latest in time? Highest on price? What do you want to do about missing values? Do you have at least 1000 observations for each distinct `name`? If not, what happens? Too vague, especially without any example data or attempts at code.

Comment: What are last observations? highest on price
What do you want to do with missing values? There are no missing values.

Comment: Please edit your question, including answers to my other queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't delete (taken to mean `drop`) observations just because they are not needed for some purpose. Given  distinct values of `name` then a new variable `ntoflag`

```
bysort name (price) : gen ntoflag = floor(_N / 1000)
```

will automatically be 0 if the number of observations is less than 1000

and so considering the complementary definition

```
by name: gen long ntokeep = _N - floor(_N/1000)
```

leads to

```
bysort name (price) : gen flag = _n > (_N - floor(_N/1000))
```

as a one-line solution for an indicator for observations to ignore. (Its negation is an indicator for observations to use.)

However, here is a thought experiment. Suppose you have 1000 prices and the top 7 prices are all 999. So, you want to ignore 0.1% = 1/1000. Which of those 7 do you want to ignore? Now consider that there may be different values for other variables in the same observations. In short, **you need an explicit consistent methodology for ties**.

To show how this works, here is a reproducible experiment for any Stata users with a much smaller dataset and a threshold of the top 5% by car origin.

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. bysort foreign (price) : gen flag = _n > (_N - floor(0.05 * _N))

. list foreign price if flag

     +-------------------+
     |  foreign    price |
     |-------------------|
 51. | Domestic   14,500 |
 52. | Domestic   15,906 |
 74. |  Foreign   12,990 |
     +-------------------+

. bysort foreign : su price

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-> foreign = Domestic

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
       price |         52    6072.423    3097.104       3291      15906

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-> foreign = Foreign

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
       price |         22    6384.682    2621.915       3748      12990
```